# Three modal forms, two submitting, one doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation, laravel-5

I've been wondering what's causing a form not to submit, a single page I'm creating have 3 buttons for opening separate modal boxes, that's 3 forms, 3 separate modals (Foundation 5), two of them work upon submit, but after opening the other modal form, and filling it in, clicking the submit button does nothing.

The form:

```
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'reports/' . $report->rid . '/edit/frequency', 'id' => 'frequency', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}

                                        <label>RID:</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newrid" value="{!!$report->rid!!}" readonly>

                                        <label>Day:</label> <select class="form-control" id="days" name="newday[]" multiple>
                                                                        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                                                                        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                                                        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                                                                        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                                                                        <option value="friday">Friday</option>
                                                                        <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
                                                                        <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
                                                                        </select>

                                        <label>Scheduled Time:</label> <select id="newsched" class="form-control" name="newsched">
                                        <?php
                                            $s_start = "00:00:00";
                                            $s_end = "23:45:00";
                                            $stStart = strtotime($s_start);
                                            $stEnd = strtotime($s_end);
                                            $stNow = $stStart;
                                            while($stNow <= $stEnd){
                                              $stime= date("H:i:s",$stNow);
                                              echo "<option value = '".$stime."'>".$stime."</option>";
                                              $stNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$stNow);
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>

                                        <label>Expected Complete Time:</label> <select id="newect" class="form-control" name="newect">
                                        <?php
                                            $e_start = "00:00:00";
                                            $e_end = "23:45:00";
                                            $eStart = strtotime($e_start);
                                            $eEnd = strtotime($e_end);
                                            $eNow = $eStart;
                                            while($eNow <= $eEnd){
                                              $estime= date("H:i:s",$eNow);
                                              echo "<option value = '".$estime."'>".$estime."</option>";
                                              $eNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$eNow);
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <label>SLA Time:</label> <select id="newsla" class="form-control" name="newsla">
                                            <?php
                                                $start = "00:00:00";
                                                $end = "23:45:00";
                                                $tStart = strtotime($start);
                                                $tEnd = strtotime($end);
                                                $tNow = $tStart;
                                                while($tNow <= $tEnd){
                                                  $time= date("H:i:s",$tNow);
                                                  echo "<option value = '".$time."'>".$time."</option>";
                                                  $tNow = strtotime('+15 minutes',$tNow);
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>

                                        <label>Hours until report Expires (can be left blank to expire at end of calendar day):</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newexp" id="expire_time" value="" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" />

                                        <label>Time Zone:</label> <select id="newtz" class="form-control" type="te

xt" name="newtz">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value='America/Los_Angeles'>America/Los_Angeles </option>
                                    <option value='Europe/London'>Europe/London </option>
                                    <option value='US/Mountain'>US/Mountain </option>
                                    <option value='US/Eastern'>US/Eastern </option>
                                    <option value='GMT'>GMT </option>
                                    <option value='Europe/Bucharest'>Europe/Bucharest </option>
                                    <option value='Europe/Istanbul'>Europe/Istanbul </option>
                                    <option value="US/Alaska">US/Alaska</option>
                                    <option value="US/Central">US/Central</option>
                                    <option value="US/Eastern">US/Eastern</option>
                                    <option value="US/Mountain">US/Mountain</option>
                                    <option value="US/Pacific">US/Pacific</option>
                                    <option value="US/Hawaii">US/Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="Africa/Johannesburg">Africa/Johannesburg</option>
                                    <option value="Asia/Manila">Asia/Manila</option>
                                    <option value="Asia/Tokyo">Asia/Tokyo</option>
                                    <option value="Asia/Hong_Kong">Asia/Hong_Kong</option>
                                    <option value="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur">Asia/Kuala_Lumpur</option>
                                    <option value="Europe/Amsterdam">Europe/Amsterdam</option>
                                    <option value="Europe/London">Europe/London</option>
                                    <option value="Europe/Istanbul">Europe/Istanbul</option>
                                    </select>   
    {!! Form::submit('Add Frequency', array('class' => 'button default radius','form' => 'frequency')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I'm using Foundation 5 in Laravel so I'm not sure if there's a limit with regards to number of form::open in a single blade or what not. The form is tested in a separate blade view and it submits (along with all the js), so not sure if it's the fact that they're in three separate modal boxes or three post forms aren't allowed in a single blade.

Answer (score 0):

Got my own answer. A table with an id = 'frequency' is causing the confusion with the form, which happens to have the same id.